# How to add in Linq to EF data in list form to Class Object C#?

Tags: c#, list, linq, object, linq-to-entities

My class User is,

```
public class User
{
    public string Username
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Password
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string [] RoleName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Linq to EF,

```
var innerJoinQuery =
                                (from u
                                in db.Users
                                join ur in db.UserRoles
                                    on u.UserID equals ur.UserID
                                join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleID equals r.RoleID
                                select new {
                                    Username=u.Username,
                                    Password=u.Password,
                                    RoleName = r.RoleName, }).ToList();
```

it result is,

```
Username = "Abc" Password="123"  RoleName = "Admin"
Username = "Test" Password="1234"  RoleName = "User"
Username = "Abc" Password="123"  RoleName = "Super User"
```

Manualy i add data in User class object,

```
List<Models.User> UserList = new List<Models.User>();
UserList.Add(new Models.User { Username ="Abc",Password="123",RoleName = new string[] {"Admin","Supe User"} });
UserList.Add(new Models.User { Username = "Test", Password = "1234", RoleName = new string[] { "User" } });
```

How to add linq to query data in List Object
If you don not understand my question kindly let me know

Thanks

EDITED:

this is not hardcode for these values it can be more than this depend upon query result

Comment: If this list is used outside the current method, create a new type to contain the task-relevant information and the list: eg “IList<UserSummary>”. Then select, eg. “Select(u => new UserSummary { Name = u.Username })”. The problem with the current code is that [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) cannot be usefully used outside a context where the type can be inferred.

Comment: While the EF type itself _can_ be used, I recommend using task-relevant types to separate EF/queryable from downstream usages when applicable.

Comment: It is not using outside method can you give example in detail

Comment: If it is used only inside the method then [var keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) can be used to allow type inference in many cases: var d = users.Select(u => new { Name = u.Username }); string x = d.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == “Hello!”); Note that the anonymous type (new {..}) is never given a name in code. Because it has no name, List<“no name”> isn’t possible; and with var it doesn’t matter.

Comment: @john you use EF core or EF for .NetFramework?

Comment: EF .NetFramework

Comment: @john i'm confused here, we have result of ``innerJoinQuery`` and you need to add it to ``UserList ``? or you want the result of ``innerJoinQuery`` like ``UserList``? can you tag me in your comment if you respond me.

Comment: I want to add in UserList

Comment: @john, how about ``group new { u.Username,u.Password,r.RoleName} by new {u.Username,u.Password} into groupedUser select new User{UserName = groupedUser.Key.UserName, Password = groupedUser.Key.Password, RoleName = groupedUser.Select(x=>x.RoleName).ToArray()}`` and use ``.AddRange`` to add the result to ``UserList``

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to instantiate anonymous types instead of `Models.User`?

```
var resultList = (
       ...
       select new {
            Username=u.Username,
            Password=u.Password,
            RoleName = new [r.RoleName] }
   )
   .ToList();

resultList.Add(new {
            Username=u.Username,
            Password=u.Password,
            RoleName = r.RoleName })
```

Number and names of fields should be the same in both cases.

### Update

If you want to do it vise versa, than change your `innerJoinQuery` select statement to selecting `Models.User`, not an anonymous type:

```
var innerJoinQuery = (
       ...
       select new Models.User {
            Username=u.Username,
            Password=u.Password,
            RoleName = new [] {r.RoleName} // assuming you have string in database
       }
   )
   .ToList();

UserList.AddRange(innerJoinQuery);
```

If you want to join on local collection inside the query then, AFAIK it is not possible, because EF will not be able to translate that to SQL.

### Update 2

Have missed that you have array in your `Models.User` and  `The array type 'System.String[]' cannot be initialized in a query result` by your version of EF. so introducing a new `Select` after `ToList` is your way out:

```
var innerJoinQuery = (
       ...
       select new  {
            Username=u.Username,
            Password=u.Password,
            RoleName = r.RoleName
       }
   )
   .ToList()
   .Select(u => new Models.User {
            Username=u.Username,
            Password=u.Password,
            RoleName = new [] {r.RoleName}
       });

UserList.AddRange(innerJoinQuery);
```

Comment: In your answer you are adding query result in result list i dont understand i want to add inner join query result in List<Model.user>

Comment: i am getting error on RoleName = r.RoleName line can not convert string to string[] can you check my User model class

Comment: @john I've already fixed that =)) change it to `RoleName = new [] {r.RoleName}`

Comment: now i am getting this error (The array type 'System.String[]' cannot be initialized in a query result. Consider using 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' instead.)  :(